# The Flash - Why didn't any meta-humans attack before Barry awakening?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

After watching the complete first season, I still don't understand...

Where were the meta-humans and why they didn't appear before Barry Allen awakening ( only nine months after )?

Comment: I think the answer to that question addresses yours.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. The answer to the other question explains that the other meta-humans most likely didn't enter into coma, strengthening the idea that they should have been active. (To be fair, the answer states that at least one meta-human was active during the month before Barry went out of coma, but it leaves a 8 month gap)

Comment: To try to answer the question, I think there is so far no answer given in the show, but it is unlikely that no meta-human had been active just after the particule accelerator accident. Note that not all meta-humans turns bad, and it is possible that meta-humans with anecdotal powers were active without appearing on the show. Also, Wells needed Barry to become a hero to fulfill his plan, so he may have cleared the city from bad meta-humans before Barry awakes from coma.